# Logstash configuration to parse 0 size aws alb log file

Tags: amazon-s3, gzip, logstash-configuration

While parsing AWS alb log with logstash s3 plugin it throws "We cannot uncompress the gzip file" when 0 size gz comes up

```
present logstash config:

input {
  s3 {
    bucket => "bucket-production-logs"
    access_key_id => "${ACCESS_KEY}"
    secret_access_key => "${SECRET_KEY}"
    region => "${REGION}"
    prefix => "web-alb-logs/"
  }
}
```